# Mysql - Cruzamento de informação entre tabelas (Selects)

Tags: banco-de-dados, node.js, mysql

Eu estou a tentar fazer uma tabela que apresente um conjunto de elementos, em que se um determinado id estiver noutra tabela, então esse elemento não poderá estar na primeira.

```
Albums     | id1 | id2 (Foreign Key)|       

Capas| id2 |                          

Compras| id3 | id1 (Foreign Key da Tabela1)|   id4 |

Clientes| id4 |
```

O meu objetivo é apresentar os Albums, excluindo aqueles que já estão associados a um determinado Cliente.

De certa forma, percebi que:

```
select * from Albums inner join Capas using(id2);
```

Permite-me obter tudo.

e

```
select * from Clientes inner join Compras using(id4) inner join
Albums using(id1) inner join Capas using(id2) where id4 ='1';
```

Permite-me obter os resultados para um determinado Cliente.

Logicamente pensei que para obter aquilo teria de juntar de certa forma ambas as ordens, contudo ainda não consegui resultados positivos.

Se me pudessem ajudar agradecia bastante!!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que consegui entender faça:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (Albuns INNER JOIN Capas ON (Albuns.id2 = Capas.id2)) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (Compras INNER JOIN Clientes ON Compras.id4 = Clientes.id4) ON (Albuns.id1 = Compras.id1) 
WHERE Compras.id3 IS NULL;
```

O que não entendi é aonde se encaixa o "Inserts" do título.